# redux saga not being executed

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-saga

React newb here. I am trying to write login page that executes a Saga. But the Saga never executes. Second problem is if I hit the submit button again then handleSubmitLogin is not called a second time. Bit lost.

```
LoginPage.js
handleSubmitLogin = (values, dispatch) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.props.dologin(values.username)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('handleSubmitLogin error ' + error);
    });
};

actionCreators.js
export function dologin(payload) {
    console.log('dologin happens OK (first time)');
    return {
        type : 'DO_LOGIN',
        payload
    }
};

sagas.js
function* loginRequested(action) {
    console.log('loginRequested never happens');
}

function* mySaga() {
    yield takeLatest('DO_LOGIN', loginRequested);
}

export default function* sagas() {
    console.log('inside sagas happens OK!');
    yield [ mySaga() ]
}
```

Comment: Sagas are quite advanced stuff.  If you are just learning react and redux I do recommend you to stick with simpler middlewares (`redux-thunk`, `redux-promise-middleware`) And come back to sagas when you do hit the limitations of those middlewares in your code.

Comment: If you do decide to stick with sagas (because they are awesome) I recommand reading https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/ErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with the `handlSubmitLogin` method. It probably doesn't need to return anything and definitely doesn't need to use a promise.

It should dispatch an action using `react-redux` dispatch. The method should probably look something like this.

```
handleSubmitLogin = (values, dispatch) => {
    dispatch(this.props.dologin(values.username));
};
```

Error handling etc should happen in the saga.